# Is there an Image or Pic format( ex K Jpg, png etc) for Logo that should be be able to maintain aspect ratio.?

Tags: image, resize, aspect-ratio

Is there an Image or Pic format( ex Jpg, png etc) for Logo that should be be able to maintain aspect ratio. Disable middle points while resizing in programs like word,excel,ppt,paint etc .

My Employees Drag the logo from middle points so that its aspect Ratio Changes causing logo to loose it standard design.

How can we resolve this issue.? (Other than resizing from corner point as they are not following the procedure . Is there a image format with Only corner resizing?

Answer (score 0):

No. Every image format can be stretched. There is no image format that can prevent any kind of mutation by any program which manipulates its data. Sounds like more of a staff training issue to me. Try using `Ctrl` or similar modifier key to maintain aspect ratio whilst resizing.